# Cache policy in Parse.com service

Tags: http-headers, parse-platform

I know that cache policy can be set if we are using queries in Parse.com service  (Ex:)

```
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Players");
query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
```

but how to do it if i use only Parse's Rest API? Object's model + network layer inside the app are independent from parse. All i need from it - json with data.

```
curl -X GET   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: hgjsdgfsjfjsdf"   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: kjsdhfjsfhsdfbjsdfsdhjf"   https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Players
```

This GET works, but without caching support. If there any workaround? Many thanks.

Comment: The caching is on the client side. If you are using the REST api directly, you will have to implement your own caching solution.

Comment: query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE); for exanmple changes HTTPHeaders in server's response. I need a way to change server's response headers in order to allow caching. AFHttpNetworkig for iOS can work with cache, but it needs propers headers filelds

Comment: Have you tried setting Cache-Control headers in your request?

Comment: Hm, no.Now I'm getting   "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"; What will be the correct header, that will tell the server , that caching i want it to allow caching?

Comment: Not sure, you'll have to experiment. Try setting max-age with a non-zero value, and see what you get back.

Comment: My understanding of the caching directive though is that it controls the caching behavior of the *server* not the client. The query.setCachePolicy on the other hand modifies the caching behavior on the client.

Comment: No, setting any cache-control value in request doesn't influence response headers values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62734/discussion-between-tom-erik-stower-and-alex).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing server cache with local cache. The query cache policy is about local cache. In the case of the iOS SDK, Parse probably uses file caching or similar, indicated by the following from the docs:

> It's often useful to cache the result of a query on disk. This lets
>   you show data when the user's device is offline, or when the app has
>   just started and network requests have not yet had time to complete.
>   Parse takes care of automatically flushing the cache when it takes up
>   too much space.
>
> The default query behavior doesn't use the cache, but you can enable
>   caching by setting query.cachePolicy. For example, to try the network
>   and then fall back to cached data if the network is not available:
>   (https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-caching/iOS)

Your example (`NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE`) is documented as follows for the iOS SDK

> `kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache`
>   The query first tries to load from the network, but if that fails, it loads results from the cache. If neither network nor cache succeed, there is a PFError.

This has nothing to do with the cache-control headers. The cache-control directives modify the caching behavior of the server.

If you want to use the REST API, as opposed to the provided SDK, and want client-side caching, you will have to implement that yourself.